# I would like do a zip compression with password in R

Tags: r, zip, gzip

I want encrypt this file with a default password programming in R. How can I do?

```
zip("C:/Users/user/Downloads/myarchive.zip", 
    files="C:/Users/user/Downloads/example.txt", 
    flags = "-r9X")
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
PASSWORD <- "BillMurray"

zip("C:/Users/user/Downloads/myarchive.zip", 
    files="C:/Users/user/Downloads/example.txt", 
    flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD))
```

Comment: zip("myarchive.zip", files, flags = "-r9XjP PASSWORD", extras = "", zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip"))

Comment: The code mentioned was not working so I changed the 3rd line of code to below and worked for me.

`flags = paste0("-p", PASSWORD, " ", " a -tzip"), `