# Zip compression with password in R

Tags: r, zip, password-protection

I managed to zip my .csv files using library(zip) in R.

```
library(zip)
Zip_Files <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = ".csv$")
zip::zipr(zipfile = "TestZip.zip", files = Zip_Files)
```

However, I can't zip it with password using "flags" command. I tried to replicate using the solution below but is not working.

[I would like do a zip compression with password in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112701/i-would-like-do-a-zip-compression-with-password-in-r)

```
PASSWORD <- "abc"
zip::zipr(zipfile = "TestZip.zip", files = Zip_Files,flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD))
```

or

```
zip("TestZip.zip", 
files=Zip_Files, 
flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD))
```

Error Message:

```
Error in zip::zipr(zipfile = "TestZip.zip", files = Zip_Files, flags = paste("--password",  : unused argument (flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD))
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than showing us what you did that worked, show us what you did, that didn't work and also the error you maybe got.

Comment: thanks @Humpelstielzchen. Added in.

Comment: Well you are using the function `zipr()` from the `zip`-package, which doesn't have an argument `flags=`. In the question you linked they are using the base R function `zip`. Try using that.

Comment: Hi @Humpelstielzchen, I tried with this 
    PASSWORD <- "abc"
zip("TestZip.zip", 
    files=Zip_Files, flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD)). I dont hit any error but I cant see the zip file in my directory.