# Create an encrypted zip archive and set the encryption method

Tags: r, encryption, zip, archive

I want to create a zip archive from within R that is password-protected. I got this running with the code from here: [I would like do a zip compression with password in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112701/i-would-like-do-a-zip-compression-with-password-in-r)

Now, as I understand, this will use the default encryption method, which is ZipCrypto. Any ideas how I could change the code so that I can set the encryption method to AES256.

I have 7zip installed as my archiving tool.

The following code doesn't work:

```
zip('file2.zip', 
    files = 'test.txt',
    extras = list(paste("--password", 'pwd123'),
                  paste("--em", "AES256")))
```

Probably because the command is using Windows default tool for zipping. Not sure how I can a) tell R to use 7zip for archiving and b) to use 7zips attributes to set the encryption method.

Comment: @SirKimani, your suggested edit appears to be an attempt to answer the question. I recommend posting as an answer, or at least the gist of your edit-suggestions as a comment.

Comment: in Any case, the suggested solution in the edit doesn't work and returns the following message/error: `Command Line Error:
Too long switch:
-r9X`